# Can't auto-generate Provisioning Profile and Certificate

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm new to NativeScript development and am trying to get my app installed on my personal iPhone for testing.

When attempting to auto-generate the Provisioning Profile and Certificate using my Apple ID, I get an error:

> An error has occurred while generating the certificate and mobile
>   provision. Reason: Two-step verification not supported at the moment..

I've logged into my Apple ID management page at: https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage but there is no option to turn two-factor authentication off.

The "Help" instructions on the NativeScript site: https://docs.nativescript.org/sidekick/user-guide/code-signing/code-signing-for-ios/code-signing-assistance only have the auto-generate steps.

I tried going to: https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/ but that tells me "Access Unavailable" and that I have to be enrolled in a developer program.

What do I need to do to create the Certificate and Provision my app?

I should add that the NativeScript site instructions also appear to be out of date as the Apple Developer Site pages don't have any of the navigational elements they're referring to, which further complicates things for beginners.

My guess is that at one point all of this was free and now Apple charges $99 a year for a developer account, otherwise none of this content shows up according to the docs on the NativeScript site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still create iOS apps and deploy them onto your device, but under the free version, you have 7 days for a provision. This year Apple also enforced 2-factor authentication, but this is not required for free accounts:

https://developer.apple.com/support/authentication/

> Who is required to enable it? Only developers with the Account Holder
>   role (formerly the “Team Agent”) in the Apple Developer Program, Apple
>   Developer Enterprise Program, or iOS Developer University Program need
>   to enable two-factor authentication. Developers who are registered for
>   a free account or who have other team roles are not required to enable
>   two-factor authentication.

Its always been nightmare to manage this stuff but if you really do have a free account from Apple, use Sidekick's feature to manage this for you:
https://docs.nativescript.org/sidekick/user-guide/code-signing/code-signing-for-ios/code-signing-assistance

Remember if you have 2-factor auth turned on, you will not be able to use this feature.

Comment: I see. So I really need a paid account if I want to deploy anything for more than 7 days :)

Comment: I created a paid developer account, so we'll see how far I get. Thanks for the help.

Comment: After creating my paid profile I was able to get my app provisioned and it's now running locally on my phone.